# Difference in Pronunciation between sprechen and sprächen

Tags: difference, pronunciation

I would think that they were the same, however I talked with a guy and he said that there was a difference in pronunciation.  He said them both, but I couldn't tell the difference.  What is the difference?  (IPA would be nice)

Comment: It's the length of the /ɛ/ sound — that's different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google, erster Treffer für *IPA sprechen sprächen*:

- [sprechen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sprechen) IPA: [ˈʃpʀɛçn̩], von da zu:
- [sprächen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/spr%C3%A4chen) IPA: [ˈʃpʀɛːçn̩]

Dort ist sogar ein Hörbeispiel für *sprechen*.

Comment: Just for people who don't know IAP notation: the _ä_ in _sprächen_ is a long _ä_ whereas the _e_ in _sprechen_ is short (but also pronounced like a _ä_).

Comment: I did a google search, but I guess English google is not as good for german questions as google.de.

Comment: The question was about sprächen, not spräche.